# Internal operations for a PC to copy data from an external USB drive to an internal HD?

Tags: architecture, storage, hardware, cpu-architecture

I was asked to the details of operations about how to copy data from an external storage to an internal storage in a computer.  The info I could find is about how a CPU fetches data from RAM.

My Question: Please describe internal operations for a PC to copy data from an external USB drive to an internal HD?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but this question is probably too broad for stackoverflow.

Comment: For the people who down voted my question... I couldn't find the clear explanation to solve this question, and I don't have backgrounds in storage protocols.  And no, it's not a hw problem.  I'm trying to find some pointers and help to understand.  It would be more constructive to tell me which forum is more suitable for my question or recommend me some resources I can learn myself than simply down vote my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*If this is homework question* the following would suffice; else the following is missing too many details and you should not use it.

1. When you plug in a USB drive, the USB driver presents the USB drive as a device that can read/write files.
2. To copy files, the PC Operating system initiates a file copy operation.

   2a. The bytes (blocks) are read from the file on USB into RAM. To do this the OS file driver issues instructions to the USB driver, which then initiates (most likley) a DMA transfer of bytes into computer RAM.

   2b. The file system driver interprets the bytes into files

   2c. The file computer then initiates copy to hard disk. Which is basically from RAM -> send instructions to hard disk driver -> which initiates a DMA transfer to disk.

DMA === Direct Memory Access

If you need more details, then SO is not the right forum. You could start with reading about USB protocol (1 book), then SCSI protocol (1 book), then Hard disk cylinders, platters, heads and such (1 book) === basically do a CS engineering course.